# for what values of the parameter is the matrix diagonazible?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

for what values of the real parameter t the matrix diagonizable?
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2t & 1 & 0 \\
3t & 0 & 0 \\ 
t  & 0 & -t
\end{pmatrix}$$

I can't find a solution any help?

Comment: **Hint:** When the matrix has three _different_ eigenvalues (the characteristic polynomial has three different roots), then it is certainly diagonalizable. If you're only interested in _real_ diagonalization, that will certainly be impossible when some of the eigenvalues are comples. Only the a few $t$ there there is a double root need to be investigated one by one.

Comment: ok thanks, i thought maybe there would be some faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\left|\begin{pmatrix}
2t & 1 & 0 \\
3t & 0 & 0 \\ 
t  & 0 & -t
\end{pmatrix}-\lambda I\right|=
\left|\begin{pmatrix}
2t-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
3t & -\lambda & 0 \\ 
t  & 0 & -t-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}\right|
=-(t+\lambda)(\lambda(\lambda-2t)-3t)=0
$$
The roots are
$\lambda =-t$,
$\lambda=t\pm\sqrt{t^2+3 t}$

so you need $t>0$ and $t^2+3 t>0$, i.e.  $t < -3$ or $t > 0$

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is 
\begin{equation}
p(x) = {x}^{3}-t{x}^{2}- \left( 2\,{t}^{2}+3\,t \right) x-3\,{t}^{2}
\end{equation}

Which has roots: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}[ccc]
\\ x_1 = -t,& x_2 = t+\sqrt{t^2+3t},& x_3 = t-\sqrt{t^2+3t}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

The values for which $x_2,x_3$ exists are such that $t^2 + 3t \geq 0$

I'll let you fill in the details.